# Python: module cannot find other modules in its own directory when imported

Tags: python, file, module, package

I'm adding a python module from a path in the parent directory of the current script I am working on.
The file structure looks like this:

- main

  - scripts

    - myscript.py

  - package

    - module1
    - module2
    - module3
    - init file

where myscript.py is importing module1, module2, and module3. module3 relies on and imports module1 and module2. When I try importing module1 and module2, it works fine. However, when I try importing module3, it throws a module not found error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'module1'. How am I meant to import module3?

module3 runs fine when I run it by itself. In module3 I've tried to sys.append the package directory directly. I've also tried taking away the init file and modifying the init file to include all files from the package. None of this has worked an I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: show us your actual code